# Mix two SASS variables inside a loop

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have few scss variables which looks like :

```
$box-bg1: #7a8360;
$box-bg2: #918261;
$box-bg3: #6a8177;
$box-bg4: #686f5e;
```

I want to use these variables inside a for,  like :

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
  .locationBox:nth-child(#{$i}) { background: $box-bg#{$i}; }
}
```

After compiling code i get this error : Syntax error: Undefined variable: "$box-bg", which looks like the `#{$i}` variable does not make any sense for my code.
Is there a way to use a variable inside a loop like this?

Note : I also use compass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sass does not support variable variables.  To programatically create your selectors, you would have to do it using lists:

```
$box-bg: #7a8360, #918261, #6a8177, #686f5e;

@for $i from 1 through length($box-bg) {
  .locationBox:nth-child(#{$i}) { background: nth($box-bg, $i); }
}
```

Output:

```
.locationBox:nth-child(1) {
  background: #7a8360;
}

.locationBox:nth-child(2) {
  background: #918261;
}

.locationBox:nth-child(3) {
  background: #6a8177;
}

.locationBox:nth-child(4) {
  background: #686f5e;
}
```